# Change color of a disabled control

Tags: android

How to change control color of a disabled EditText or any control (not greyed out anymore), preferably using themes in styles.xml or direct attribute on layout.xml, not in code

Comment: Without using codes, means are you willing to make it permanently disabled, and grey colored with in whole life cycle.

Comment: yes, i just combo it with TextLayout for a titled display

Comment: Create a custom selector drawable